# common profile to record ssh sessions

Tags: linux, bash

I need to be able to record all ssh sessions on my server. After fumbling around with pam.d auditd, I found this [enter link description here](http://www.2daygeek.com/2014/02/how-to-record-save-all-user-terminal-activity-automatically/). And it looks to be working pretty well. However, when you "clear" the screen, your session log gets wiped as well. Is is possible to open a new log file when this happens?

Here is the code it is asking to put in the /etc/profile file.

```
# Record terminal sessions.
if [ "x$SESSION_RECORD" = "x" ]
then
timestamp=`date "+%m%d%Y%H%M"`
output=/var/log/session/session.$USER.$$.$timestamp
SESSION_RECORD=started
export SESSION_RECORD
script -t -f -q 2>${output}.timing $output
exit
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`script` isn't really designed for that use case. From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/script):

> `Script` works best with commands that do not manipulate the screen, the results are meant to emulate a hardcopy terminal.

This is incorrect, however:

> when you "clear" the screen, your session log gets wiped as well.

Every character that is input or output is added to the log file, including the terminal codes which `clear` uses to clear the screen. If you do a `cat -v /var/log/session/session...` to show all non-printing characters, you will see all of the commands listed.